# configuration.setAllowedOrigins is not allowing defined multiple domain names

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

configuration.setAllowedOrigins() is not setting multiple defined domain names.

This is running in spring 3.X with class based configuration.
Not working:

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins (ImmutableList.of("http://*.domain1.com","http://*.domain2.com","https://*.domain3.com"))
```

---

Its working fine if i specify the sub domain names as below.
Working:

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins (ImmutableList.of("http://test1.domain1.com","http://test2.domain2.com","https://test3.domain3.com"))
```

Dont want to specify the sub-domain names . so want to use * in place of sub domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `config.addAllowedOrigin("*");`

Comment: * - it will allow all domains .
i want it should be allow all sub-domain of specified domains.

Comment: Then you should specify them as you did. Check this post also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains